# JNIEnv_::DeleteGlobalRef - Core Dump in Linux

Tags: java, java-native-interface, segmentation-fault

I have a Java program that loads a C++ `.so` file and we have Jace (JNI) in the middle. When I run the Java program and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> it crashes with the below StackTrace:

> env->DeleteGlobalRef(globalRef);
>
> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f79c7de5493, pid=7467,
>   tid=0x00007f79d4f5e700
>
> C  [libjaced.so+0x44493]  JNIEnv_::DeleteGlobalRef(_jobject*)+0x17

Comment: You need to post a complete example so others can reproduce your problem.

Comment: System.out.println("Begin ..!!");
System.loadLibrary("MYDLL");
System.out.println("Library Loaded");

call a native method from Java Code which is present in library that we have loaded

Press Crtl C

Comment: Do you have the source code for this JNI in the middle?

Comment: ???  You wouldn't throw your car keys at an auto mechanic, say, "It don't work!", and then just walk off, would you?

Comment: Stack: [0x00007f127beff000,0x00007f127c000000],  sp=0x00007f127bffe7e0,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libjaced.so+0x44493]  JNIEnv_::DeleteGlobalRef(_jobject*)+0x17
C  [libjaced.so+0x42aea]  jace::helper::deleteGlobalRef(JNIEnv_*, _jobject*)+0x2c
C  [libjaced.so+0x35ebe]  jace::JClassImpl::~JClassImpl()+0x5e

Comment: public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      System.out.println("Begin ..!!");
      System.loadLibrary("JavaApi");
      System.out.println("Library Loaded");
      Shutdown shutdown = new Shutdown();
     try
      {

         JAVATEST mpf;
         mpf = new JAVATEST (0,false,false);
   }

Comment: We use Jace which generate the JNI code

Comment: I see the same except I wrote the code in the middle. Instead of your ` JNIEnv_::DeleteGlobalRef(_jobject*)+0x17` I get the crash at `+0x14`. I am digging into it, it happens on `JNI_OnUnload()` when freeing GLobal-refs. Have you solved yours?

Comment: Hi. Did you ever solve this?